# Hello, I need some help converting this c code into a parallel with OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

As in the title need some help converting this c code into parallel with openmp. 
The code description is Walk and chew bubblegum on two separate threads, instead of in sequence

```
#include <unistd.h> // sleep()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int walk(int secs);
int chew_gum(int secs);

int main() {
    double t0 = omp_get_wtime(); // Start timer

    walk(5); // Walk for five seconds
    chew_gum(5); // Chew bubblegum for five seconds

    double t1 = omp_get_wtime(); // End timer
    printf("Seconds elapsed: %f\n", t1 - t0);
    return 0;
}

// DO NOT CHANGE CODE BELOW THIS LINE
int walk(int secs) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Walking...\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int chew_gum(int secs) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Chewing bubblegum...\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you consulted OpenMP documentation yet for an example? If not, please do so first, and then let us know *with details* about any trouble you run into when adapting that example for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of the following openmp directives

- parallel : create a group of thread
- single : block is executed by one thread only

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    fputs("b0\n",stdout);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {
            // one thread only
            fputs("b1\n",stdout);
            sleep(5);
            fputs("e1\n",stdout);
        }
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {
            // one thread only
            fputs("b2\n",stdout);
            sleep(5);
            fputs("e2\n",stdout);
        }
    }
    fputs("e0\n",stdout);
}
```

[source : OpenMP 4.5 API C/C++ Syntax Reference Guide](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-4.5-1115-CPP-web.pdf)